# SQL query to read nested JSON object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

How to read JSON object matching query params? I want to filter data for video urls which only contains query params from metadata column and replace it by the removing the query params.

| metadata |
| --- |
| {"video-url":"xyz.com/video/xy4jnj?pubtool=oembed","provider":"some-video","video-id":"x8cse6q"} |
| {"video-url":"xyz.com/video/x8cse6q?pubtool=oembed","provider":"some-video","video-id":x8cse6q} |
| {"video-url":"xyz.com/video/x8cse6q","provider":"some-video","video-id":"x8cse6q"} |

```
select * from content where metadata.video-url ilike %?pubtool%
```

Expected to return rows which consists of query param in the metadata column for the field video-url.

Comment: LIKE is used for text, not for JSON. Did you check the manual? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL` are two different products. Please keep only one tag for the DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

You need irst to extract the vidourl from the json and compare it to your search pattern.

You need to convert the result to varchar to use like

```
SELECT
"metadata"
FROM video 
WHERE ("metadata"  #> '{"video-url"}')::varchar like '%?pubtool%'
```

| metadata |
| --- |
| {"video-url":"xyz.com/video/xy4jnj?pubtool=oembed","provider":"some-video","video-id":"x8cse6q"} |
| {"video-url":"xyz.com/video/x8cse6q?pubtool=oembed","provider":"some-video","video-id":"x8cse6q"} |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kJFTBBpJ)

Answer (score 1):

Extracting the `video-url` from the metadata:

```sql
SELECT
  metadata->>'video-url' as "video-url"
FROM m;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/OvSRguk5)